# Eloquent relationship between vehicle and price

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

A bit confused about eloquent relationship. What's the relationship between a vehicle and its price and do I need a pivot table!

Below is my vehicle vehicle migration. Goal is to be able to query all vehicles associated with a certain price.

```
    class CreateVehiclesTable extends Migration
    
        {
        
            public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->id();
        
                    $table->string('title', 256);
                    $table->string('image')->nullable();
                    $table->integer('engineSize')->nullable();
                    $table->integer('numberSeats')->nullable();
                    $table->integer('mileage')->nullable();
                    $table->integer('power')->nullable();
                    $table->integer('doors')->nullable();
                    $table->string('fuel')->nullable();
                    $table->string('gearbox')->nullable();
                    $table->string('color')->nullable();
        
        
                    $table->integer('condition_id');
                    $table->integer('type_id');
                    $table->integer('modell_id');
                    $table->integer('year_id');
                    $table->integer('price');
        
        
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
        
      
            public function down()
            {
                Schema::dropIfExists('vehicles');
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's your table structure - migrations? Without any code it's not possible to suggest. Pls post code. If your app has a single price for vehicle then its **Vehicle hasOne Price** for eg

Comment: The docs are really good. Check it out, in case your Model doesn't exists yet: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Would you even need a relation here?

Comment: @brombeer HasOne relationship may be required if Price has extra properties like currency, mrp, lrp etc - some efforts towards data normalization

Comment: @Donkarnash what what about the price, do I need a migration and model for it? I've provided the migration. Let me know if you want me to provide more code!

Comment: If you don't have a separate table for price then there's no question about a relationship between vehicle and price - price is an attribute on Vehicle object

Comment: With this migration you can Vehicle::where('price', $price)->get() will give you all vehicles associated with the $price - if that's the only requirement and price doesn't have any extra properties then you certainly don't require a separate table for price

Comment: I've edited my question kindly check what I'm trying to achieve. Yes I don't have a separate table and I'm confused whether I should have one or not to achieve my objective

Comment: phew, thanks, now that solves what I'm trying to achieve maybe I didn't ask my question well in my original question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the model representing the records for vehicles table (your migration) is **Vehicle**

You can get all records associated with a particular price - $price = 100 for example by

```php
$vehiclesAssociatedWithPrice100 = Vehicle::where('price', 100)->get();
```

You should read Laravel docs they are really self explanatory

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database